# MVC class within class not being populated

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

Trying to make an MVC application of an existing PHP/MySql library application. I'm having trouble getting the most basic things to work, and I feel like an idiot.

I have the following classes defined:

`Book` class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int? SeriesID { get; set; }
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    etc
}
```

`Genre` class:

```
public class Genre
{
    public int GenreID { get; set; }
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

When I run this I see that each book object created has a Genre object, but it is null, and the data for the genres isn't being populated.

The `GenreId` in the book class is a foreign key

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: "The GenreId in the book class is a foreign key" is it so in your database?

Comment: It wan't originally, I added it when I started working with MVC

Answer (score 0):

The Genre property on Book should be virtual. If it isn't virtual then a plain query that just retrieves Books will always leave Genre blank. Making it virtual allows Entity Framework to create a dynamic proxy class, inherited from Book, that implements the getter of the Genre property with code to issue a query to populate and return the Genre from the database.

You've already made the  Genre's collection of Books virtual so that would work as a lazy fetching property already.

An alternative to lazy loading is to use .Include on your query to include the Genre property.